# How to cancel snapshot space only?

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

For the cancel operation, we are canceling a billing item of purchased product.

But for the cancellation of snapshot space, (not for whole storage) it returns error when we try it with same way.

How can I cancel billing item for snapshot space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following Rest request:

```
https://$user:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Billing_Item_Cancellation_Request/createObject.json

Method: Post

{  
   "parameters":[  
      {  
         "complexType":"SoftLayer_Billing_Item_Cancellation_Request",
         "accountId":123123,
         "notes":"notes test",
         "items":[  
            {  
               "complexType":"SoftLayer_Billing_Item_Cancellation_Request_Item",
               "billingItemId":101726027,
               "immediateCancellationFlag":true
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

References:

- [SoftLayer_Billing_Item_Cancellation_Request::createObject](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Billing_Item_Cancellation_Request/createObject)